# flutter - widget render thread line bug

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

Everyone can experience it at least once.
flutter widget has threaded lines created after injecting color.

- Widget Code like:

```
...
Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: ...,
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: .white,
          ),
          child: Card(
            color: .bg,
            elevation: 0,
            margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
            ),
            child: ...,
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            width: ...,
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: .bg,
              ),
            child: Card(
              color: .white,
              elevation: 0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(50)),
              ),
              child: ...,
            )
          )
        )
      ]
    );
```

- result widget preview:
  [image]

**what is this?**
**it's a bug for rendering?**

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: Please add full code or code snippet. So, can check that